# How to autofill employee details when employee name is selected in odoo?

Tags: odoo

How to get the details of employee when employee name is selected in odoo.

I have made a many2one field relating with hr.employee. but i am not able to get the results

.py code

```
class mom_person(osv.Model):
_name = 'mom.person'
_columns = { 
'emp_i' : fields.many2one('hr.employee','Attendees'),
'ename_id' : fields.many2one('mom.meeting','Attend Person'),
'depat':fields.char('Department'),
'wk_mail':fields.char('Mail'),
'wk_cnt':fields.char('Contact'),
}

def get_emp_det(self, cr, uid, ids, emp_i, context=None):
val = {}
emp_id = self.pool.get('hr.employee')
if emp_i:
for rec in emp_id.browse(cr,uid,emp_i,context=context):
val = {
'depat': rec.department_id,
'wk_mail':rec.work_email,
'wk_cnt':rec.work_phone,
}   
return val  

mom_person()
```

and xml code

```
<tree string="Employee name" editable="bottom">
<field name="emp_i" onchange="get_emp_det(emp_i)"/>
<field name="depat"/>
<field name="wk_mail"/>
<field name="wk_cnt"/>
</tree>
/field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have to change the onchanage method in your .py file try do to given below :

```
def get_emp_det(self, cr, uid, ids, emp_i, context=None):
    v={}
    if emp_i:
        employee = self.pool.get('hr.employee').browse(cr, uid, emp_i, context=context)
        if employee.department_id.id:
            v['depat'] = employee.department_id and employee.department_id.id or False
        if employee.work_email:
            v['wk_mail'] = employee.work_email
        if employee.work_phone:
            v['wk_cnt'] = employee.work_phone

return {'value': v}
```

You can try above onchange and restart the server and see the result

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: well, thanks a lot, but the results are not reflecting

Comment: means u can not get that data in your form ??

Comment: u change the xml as well <field name="emp_i" on_change="get_emp_det(emp_i)"/>

Comment: I havent got the details in the form

Comment: update the module and restart the server and check again

Comment: add some detail in employee form then after check again

Comment: added, but not displaying

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: please send your module on c.dasadiya74@gmail.com and I will check and forward to u

Comment: I have sent. please check

Comment: @Shravya Shetty, please check your mail i have send your updated module to u

Comment: thanks a lot, ok i will check, what were the corrections ? and where

Comment: okey good I made correction in py method indend as well as xml tag with on_change attribute of that field.

Comment: oki,,thats great, but one minute problem now, department isn't appearing as department name, since it is department_id...

Comment: i think in your base hr module some one made that change.